# rJava: non-zero exit status

Tags: java, r, rstudio, rjava

I have been trying to install rJava using the following commands:

```
install.packages('rJava',,'http://www.rforge.net/')
```

or

```
install.packages('rJava', type = 'source', INSTALL_opts='--merge-multiarch')
```

but each time I fail due to this error:

> WARNING: JRI could NOT be built Set IGNORE=1 if you want to build
>   rJava anyway. ERROR: configuration failed for package 'rJava'. I have uninstalled and re-installed both version of java on my machine but still no help!

Does anyone has a solution ?

the full description is as below:

> install for i386
>
> - installing *source* package 'rJava' ...
>     ** package 'rJava' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked Generate Windows-specific files (src/jvm-w32) ... make: Entering directory
>     '/Users/ahkay/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpKalUob/R.INSTALL192609e43b16/rJava/src/jvm-w32'
>     C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/dlltool --as C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/as 
>     --input-def jvm.def --kill-at --dllname jvm.dll --output-lib libjvm.dll.a C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/gcc  -O2 -c -o findjava.o
>     findjava.c C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/gcc  -s -o findjava.exe findjava.o
>     make: Leaving directory
>     '/Users/ahkay/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpKalUob/R.INSTALL192609e43b16/rJava/src/jvm-w32'
>     Find Java... ./configure.win: line 15: [: too many arguments
>     JAVA_HOME=C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_202
>     === Building JRI === configure.win: line 21: [: too many arguments   JAVA_HOME=C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_202
>     R_HOME=C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-35~1.2 Creating Makefiles ... Configuration
>     done. make -C src JRI.jar make[1]: Entering directory
>     '/Users/ahkay/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpKalUob/R.INSTALL192609e43b16/rJava/jri/src'
>     C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_202/bin/javac  -d . ../RList.java
>     ../RBool.java ../RVector.java ../RMainLoopCallbacks.java
>     ../RConsoleOutputStream.java ../Mutex.java ../Rengine.java
>     ../REXP.java ../RFactor.java ../package-info.java make[1]: C:/Program:
>     Command not found make[1]: *** [Makefile.all:41:
>     org/rosuda/JRI/Rengine.class] Error 127 make[1]: Leaving directory
>     '/Users/ahkay/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpKalUob/R.INSTALL192609e43b16/rJava/jri/src'
>     make: *** [Makefile.all:19: src/JRI.jar] Error 2
>     **** WARNING: JRI could NOT be built Set IGNORE=1 if you want to build rJava anyway. ERROR: configuration failed for package 'rJava'
> - removing 'C:/Users/ahkay/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/rJava' In R CMD INSTALL In R CMD INSTALL Warning in install.packages :   installation
>     of package ‘rJava’ had non-zero exit status

Comment: I have had that problem and was able to install by downloading a zip file from CRAN and then installing from the local copy. You might try that.

Comment: unfortunately didn't help :(

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced same issue and following approach worked for me in my Mac OS 10.13.6, you can apply minor OS related changes if using in other OS.

OS:

Installing rJava Manually

```
# curl -#ROL https://www.rforge.net/rJava/snapshot/rJava_0.9-8.tar.gz
# R CMD INSTALL rJava_0.9-8.tar.gz
#  su -
```

Location you have installed R software, you might have different location.

```
#  cd /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/lib
```

I found that different Java used by R, and forcing by softlink:

```
#ln -s /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/server/libjvm.dylib libjvm.dylib
```

Remember, you need to put your JAVA_HOME in the following location in R Studio:

```
>Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME = "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home")
```

Verifying rJava working in R Studio:

```
>require(rJava)
```